# Reconfigure a Debian or Ubuntu package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, aptitude

I need to reconfigure my debian or ubuntu `postfix` package.

How can I do this?

---

NOTE:  I am [answering my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: There is a button when posting asking a question that allows you immediately write an answer, you can just use that one instead of putting up a note :)

Comment: That's what I did; however, some people aren't familiar with the policy and get a little cranky about answering your own question so quickly.  A note can't hurt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dpkg-reconfigure`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg-reconfigure) as root:

```
dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Or for a general solution:

```
dpkg-reconfigure <debian_package_name>
```